# Does master node execute actual tasks in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

My question may sound silly, but it bothers me for a long time.

[image]

The picture shown above is the components of a distributed Spark application. I think this picture indicates that the **master node** will never execute actual tasks, but only is served as a cluster manager. Is it true?

By the way, the `tasks` here refers to the user-submit tasks.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Actually this picture is not very good. It is better to think about this as shown here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/img/cluster-overview.png

Comment: In that case, shall we use a better configuration machine as master?

Comment: In general yes. Details depend on cluster manager and environment but typically you want it to be at least replicated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the master node executes the driver process and does not run tasks. Tasks run in executor processes on the worker nodes. The master node is rarely stressed from a CPU standpoint but, depending on how broadcast variables, accumulators and `collect` are used, it may be quite stressed in terms of RAM usage.

Answer (score 1):

To explain a bit more on the different roles:

The driver prepares the context and declares the operations on the data using RDD transformations and actions.

The driver submits the serialized RDD graph to the master. The master creates tasks out of it and submits them to the workers for execution. It coordinates the different job stages.

The workers is where the tasks are actually executed. They should have the resources and network connectivity required to execute the operations requested on the RDDs.